# Does a primitive (or solution) exist for this integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I found on an italian math site
[a particular integral problem](http://www.matefilia.it/scolerivolftp/problemaaprile2004.htm)
$$\int\frac{\ln^3(\sqrt x+1)}{\cos^2(\sqrt[3]x-\ln x)}\,dx$$
It remains <s>unsolved</s> since 2004.
I've tried to work on it for a long time using different kind of replacement methods.
It seems to be not possible to find/show if it owns primitive.
Does anybody have some ideas to turn around the problem?
For me it is too hard...
Thank you to all for your help.

Comment: @Parcly Taxel: thank you for your review. With reference to your actions, about creative common license added by me on original post, why is it not necessary?(I see that you are remove).